# CentOS - meaning of the boot screen progress bar layers/colors

Tags: centos, boot

Is there any meaning of the CentOS (I guess RedHat and if I remember correctly Fedora too) boot screen progress bar layers*?

[image: CentOS boot screen progress bar]
(*) Layers ~ white, lilac(?) and violet colours.

I can't figure out any good search query for this, but maybe somebody will know...

Comment: I had always assumed it was meant to indicate "hey look at me, I'm moving around." The [source code seems to bear that out](https://dpaste.de/aBdP)(that's from the function that updates the "step bar"). Although maybe someone knows more than me.

Comment: It is an illusion, mental imagery of sorts. The point is to make the boot feel faster whilst looking at the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but from the source (ply-text-progress-bar.c) it looks like you set the overall percentage done and that the different colors/layers's progress is hard coded by the following, and other functions within that file:

```
    brown_fraction = -(progress_bar->percent_done * progress_bar->percent_done) + 2 * progress_bar->percent_done;
    blue_fraction = progress_bar->percent_done;
    white_fraction = progress_bar->percent_done * progress_bar->percent_done;
```

So, it appears that it is a style choice with no underlying meaning.

Comment: lol brown = `2*percent - percent^2`, blue = `percent`, white = `percent^2`. Lame Plymouth, lame. I'll accept this as a definitive answer though.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Thank you for the bounty... I have been too lazy or not enough curios to look to the code, but fortunately Liczyrzepa answered this.

Comment: It's funny - I had wondered myself what was behind that progress bar and was curious.  When I saw the question posted here, I thought to myself, time to figure it out!  Thanks for spurring my curiosity :)

Comment: @Liczyrzepa Thanks for your answer, however IMO it's a pity that opportunity to show something meaningful on this progress bar is wasted.

Answer (score 2):

The software that is running to produce that bar is called [Plymouth](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/), and it only appears if you have `rhgb` in your kernel arguments.  It basically takes the output of the startup sequence and presents it according to the chosen theme.  In this case, it is using the `text` theme, probably because it can't start the graphical theme.

Comment: I'm aware that is startup sequence progress, I have found that is Plymouth and I prefer text mode ;) Just since I have seen it first time I'm wondering is the darkest layer a kind of task scheduling progress, medium a kind of task execution start and a brightest a task execution end or the layers just don't have any meaning (what Sukminder suggests).